# jedi-vim inconsistent with jedi output

Tags: python, vim, jedi, jedi-vim

I am using jedi-vim, and after typing the following, I get a "Pattern not found" error:

```
import numpy
numpy.
```

However, if I run the following python script, I get a long list of completions:

```
import jedi
print(jedi.Script('import numpy;numpy.').completions())
```

Since jedi-vim can successfully complete other packages, I'm not sure what is configured incorrectly, what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The vim I was using didn't have python3 support, so jedi was looking at python2.7 modules, hence no numpy. I reinstalled vim with python3 support, and it solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same symptoms, but for me I needed to make sure that vim saw my Python anaconda installation as per [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9486/how-to-change-python-interpreter-used-by-jedi-vim?newreg=54c17da945bf4482bb0c739fe2aada69).